# Facelet get object attribute

Tags: java, jsf

I try to print the name of the logged user this way:

```
<p>Welcome #{sessionScope.authUser.email}</p>
```

In the User model the get-er and set-er for the name are present.

This is the error thrown:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: For input string: "email"
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** Stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/account.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /account.xhtml: For input string: "email"
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:90)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "email"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.toInteger(ListELResolver.java:407)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:224)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:148)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    ... 35 more

INFO: Exit : render_response 6
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "email"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.toInteger(ListELResolver.java:407)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:224)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:148)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Please show the *full* stack trace and the *real* code responsible for this. The answer is in the bottommost root cause of the stack trace. The code posted so far does not seem to related to the error message in any way. Or does the exception really disappear when you remove that particular line of code?

Comment: That does not make sense. You are saying that you are trying to print the `name` and the posted stacktrace message is talking about `"email"` which is an input. You need to update your post.

Comment: updated the question. Strange thing is that I get the expected result if i call just #{sessionScope.authUser}

Comment: @βнɛƨнǤʋяʋиɢ it's the stack trace for another attribute. I tried different approaches..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<p>Welcome #{sessionScope.authUser.name}</p>
```

That line of code can impossibly have thrown this exception.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "email"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.toInteger(ListELResolver.java:407)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    ...
```

Look, there's a `ListELResolver` involved. This suggests that you have somewhere something like a

```
#{bean.list.email}
```

where `#{bean.list}` actually returns a `List` and thus needs to be accessed by an integer index using the brace notation `[]` like as follows to get the 1st item (which in turn of course should have the `email` property):

```
#{bean.list[0].email}
```

---

**Update** as per your update, the real code is

```html
<p>Welcome #{sessionScope.authUser.email}</p>
```

The `authUser` apparently implements `List` or extends one of its subclasses. This makes no sense for a managed bean. Remove the interface or the subclass from the managed bean class declaration. Just the following is sufficient:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AuthUser implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

Also, although explicitly specifying the scope like as in `#{sessionScope.authUser}` may be helpful for self-documentary purposes, this is unnecessary. Just use `#{authUser}`.

---

**Update 2** as per the comments: you seem to have manually placed an object in the session scope which is actually a `List`. This is fishy. Consider using a normal session scoped managed bean which you inject as a managed property in a request scoped bean which handles the login.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was in the managed bean. I placed in on the session the result of getResultList() instead of an getSingleResult. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, you have manually placed an object in the session scope? Why not just make it a property of a session scoped bean?

Comment: I tried to do that but I couldn't find an explicit tutorial presenting some good practices when injecting those attributes through different beans therefore I chose something I knew it works. Isn't this a good practice?

Comment: At least do not manually create beans and declare the right bean scope for the data it holds and do not mix differently scoped data in the same bean. It will guide itself.

Answer (score 0):

At first are you sure the bean exists in the session? If so, try using #{sessionScope['authUser'].name}.

Comment: That line of code can impossibly have thrown an exception with the particular message and your proposed change does technically not change anything.

Comment: Btw how do you add comments to the question without posting an answer?

Comment: You get this privilege when you earn at least 50 reputation. Below that, you can only comment on your own posts.